# Which is the best way to implement client API

Tags: design-patterns, api-design

I'm trying to figure out which would be the best API to provide to the clients of my SDK. Basically, the typical use-case would be one session instance and one renderer in one application, however, this might change in the future.

Key points: is should be easy to use from the users prospective, stable and future-proof.

**Method A:**

```java
 /**
 * The user have to create and maintain the module
 *
 * pros:
 *  -module explicitly added at construction time
 *  -uses an object that would be only available using the extension
 *
 * cons:
 *  -does not enforce one-o-one relation between renderer and session
 *  -the burden of maintaining the module leaved to the user
 *  -the burden of creating the module leaved to the user
 *  -fixed StreamingModule implementation forever
 * */
public void createSessionWithUserInstalledModule(VideoRenderer.Callbacks renderer) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.newInstance();
    StreamingModule module = new StreamingModule();
    module.useRenderer(renderer);
    factory.install(module);
    factory.create(context, sessionCreatedCallback);

}
```

**Method B:**

```java
/**
 * A static field of the module holds the instance.
 * The module will be implicitly picked up, and instantiated
 * when it's on the classpath.
 * It will be injected into the session during construction time.
 *
 * pros:
 *  -module doesn't need to be maintained by user
 *  -trivial implementation from user side
 *
 * cons:
 *  -only one renderer is possible
 *  -only one renderer will be available to all session instances
 *  -possibility of leaking the renderer instance
 * */
public void createSessionWithStaticHolder(VideoRenderer.Callbacks renderer) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.newInstance();
    StreamingModule.setRenderer(renderer);
    factory.create(context, sessionCreatedCallback);
}
```

**Method C:**

```java
/**
 * The module can be retrieved from the session instance, after the
 * session is created.
 * The module will be implicitly picked up, and instantiated
 * when it's on the classpath.
 * It will be injected into the session during construction time.
 *
 * pros:
 *  -StreamingModule implementation can be replaced in the future
 *  -session instances have their own module
 *  -only the session instance needed to be maintained (which is probably
 *  already done on the user side)
 *
 * cons:
 *  -less trivial implementation on user side
 * */
public void createSessionUsingServiceStyle(final VideoRenderer.Callbacks renderer) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.newInstance();
    factory.create(context, new SessionFactory.SessionCreationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSessionCreated(Session session) {
            StreamingModule module = session.getModule(StreamingModule.class);
            module.useRenderer(renderer);
        }
    });
}
```

I would choose the latter solution (C), as it I see it as a golden path between the ease of use and the future scalability. Please see my comments, and advise!

Comment: Which part of this is your API and which part is client code?

Comment: The methods would represent client code. The classes and related methods of _SessionFactory, StreamingModule_ would be the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost picked A, because it's simpler to use and the middle name of "the burden" is "flexibility".

Still, I'd go with the bastard child of A and C where there's no magic with the classpath to obtain the module.

Thoughts/reasoning:
Every time I hear the words 'JVM', 'implicit' and 'classpath' in the same sentence, I lose some hair and feel like I'm being hit by a bus.

Some users may find it harder to deal with the async SessionCreationCallback compared to sequential code, but that's a really just a case of RTFM about computers.